# How to add modal inside swiper slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, swiper.js

My code:

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <a href="www.example.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#123" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank');">
                    <span class="coupon-code-value">123</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="dhs-controls">
        <div class="dhs dhs-prev"></div>
        <div class="dhs dhs-next"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="123" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
```

//script for swiper slider

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
            preloadImages: false,
            freeMode: false,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            loop: false,
            grabCursor: true,
            mousewheel: false,
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,

            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.dhs-next',
                prevEl: '.dhs-prev',
            }
        });
```

In above code, both tabs and slider are working fine. Modal div exist in the code. But Modal popup is not showing when I click the modal link.

I have tried giving highest z-index value for modal class and also tried giving negative z-index value to swiper-container class. Still its not working..

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong? Is it possible that modal works with slider?

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Swiper.js has a built-in class called .modal. And in there is the default property display: none.

Just change in your .css display to block to see the modal, and then you can do an event listener to toggle the display of the modal